# I can not install Java on my debian 6 VPS

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian

I've tried to install Java 8 JDK on my Debian 6 machine now for an hour, I can't figure out how to do it. I've looked at other posts, with no luck. I am getting this error

> E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try     `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`  `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: You are using debian jessie (debian 8) not debian 6 , [please edit your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50256157/edit)

Comment: @Flax Have You managed to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the webupd8team repository in order to install `oracle-java8-installer`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

- `python-software-properties` will allow you to use `add-apt-repository`.
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` will add the repository
- `sudo apt-get update` will update the list of packages (in our case, we need to do it to fetch the packages in the repository we just added)

Comment: I tried all that :( DId not work, https://i.imgur.com/fjAwxa9.png Still getting this as the result.  https://i.imgur.com/FRhMOY2.png

Comment: can you add that to your answer, but in text? I can't see images from imgur from where I am right now

Comment: Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 17.0 kB in 1s (9,866 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@vmi181337:~# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
root@vmi181337:~#

Comment: can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, how can i do that? :/

Comment: @TwiN What to do if apt-get install software-properties-common also gives Unable to locate package error ? I also try to install java on my Debian 6 machine.. its really hard :(

Answer (score 1):

The installation process of Java 8 on debian is described on the [official documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage).

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

Install `java-package`:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install java-package && exit
```

Download the tarball ( `.tar.gz`) from [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (accept the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement). Then build the `.deb` package through the `make-jpkg` utility from the java binary (e,g: `jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz`):

```
$ make-jpkg jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

A `oracle-java8-jdk_8u171_amd64.deb` will be created in your working directory , install the `.deb` file:

```
# dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u171_amd64.deb
```

Check the java version

```
$ java -version
```

sample output (from debian 9):

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-1~deb9u1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Note** : Debian recommend the installation of the `openjdk-7-jre` package:

> Debian recommends the use of OpenJDK packages (`openjdk-7-jdk` / `openjdk-7-jre`) **instead of non-free packages** created by this utility.

Comment: Is it safe link to Debian Jessie repository, on Debian Squeeze system ?

Comment: @10101101 Welcome, It is not safe because apt will try to upgrade all package in the main repository to Jessie , it will break your system.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! Is there any working java repository for Debian 6 ?